# Find the time difference after subtracting weekend time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

| ID | START_TIME_ | END_TIME_ | TIME_DIFF | TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-18 09:58:38.906 | 2022-04-18 12:50:27.204 | 10308298 |  |
| 2 | 2022-04-18 21:26:25.671 | 2022-04-18 21:26:36.313 | 10642 |  |
| 3 | 2022-04-18 21:27:12.388 | 2022-04-18 21:27:27.227 | 14839 |  |
| 4 | 2022-04-19 09:57:40.453 | 2022-04-19 09:59:07.612 | 87159 |  |

TIME_DIFF = END_TIME_ - START_TIME_
TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS = Need to subtract the weekends and find the time difference.

I was able to calculate the difference between start_time and end time to get the time_diff, but can someone help me in getting the working_day duration by removing the weekends. (sat/sun -- 48 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '2022-04-18 09:58:38.906',  '2022-04-18 12:50:27.204'),
     (2, '2022-04-18 21:26:25.671',  '2022-04-18 21:26:36.313'),
     (3, '2022-04-18 21:27:12.388',  '2022-04-18 21:27:27.227'),
     (4, '2022-04-19 09:57:40.453',  '2022-04-29 09:59:07.612')],
    ['ID', 'START_TIME_', 'END_TIME_'])
```

- Method using higher-order functions `aggregate` and `filter`:

  ```py
  df = df.withColumn(
      'TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS',
      F.aggregate(
          F.expr("filter(sequence(to_date(START_TIME_), to_date(END_TIME_)), x -> weekday(x) < 5)"),
          F.lit(0).cast('long'),
          lambda acc, d: acc + F.least(F.date_add(d, 1), F.to_timestamp('END_TIME_')).cast('long')
                         - F.greatest(d, F.to_timestamp('START_TIME_')).cast('long')
      )    
  )
  df.show(truncate=0)
  # +---+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
  # |ID |START_TIME_            |END_TIME_              |TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS|
  # +---+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
  # |1  |2022-04-18 09:58:38.906|2022-04-18 12:50:27.204|10309                  |
  # |2  |2022-04-18 21:26:25.671|2022-04-18 21:26:36.313|11                     |
  # |3  |2022-04-18 21:27:12.388|2022-04-18 21:27:27.227|15                     |
  # |4  |2022-04-19 09:57:40.453|2022-04-29 09:59:07.612|691287                 |
  # +---+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
  ```

  Syntax for Spark 2.4+

  ```py
  df = df.withColumn(
      'TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS',
      F.expr("""
          aggregate(
              filter(sequence(to_date(START_TIME_), to_date(END_TIME_)), x -> weekday(x) < 5),
              cast(0 as long),
              (acc, d) -> acc + cast(least(date_add(d, 1), to_timestamp(END_TIME_)) as long)
                          - cast(greatest(d, to_timestamp(START_TIME_)) as long)
          )
      """)
  )
  ```
- Method using `explode` and `groupBy`:

  ```py
  df = df.withColumn('day', F.explode(F.sequence(F.to_date('START_TIME_'), F.to_date('END_TIME_'))))
  workday = (~F.dayofweek('day').isin([1, 7])).cast('long')
  seconds = F.least(F.date_add('day', 1), F.to_timestamp('END_TIME_')).cast('long') \
            - F.greatest('day', F.to_timestamp('START_TIME_')).cast('long')
  df = df.groupBy('ID', 'START_TIME_', 'END_TIME_').agg(
      F.sum(seconds).alias('TIME_DIFF'),
      F.sum(seconds * workday).alias('TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS')
  )

  df.show(truncate=0)
  # +---+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
  # |ID |START_TIME_            |END_TIME_              |TIME_DIFF|TIME_SPENT_WORKING_DAYS|
  # +---+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
  # |1  |2022-04-18 09:58:38.906|2022-04-18 12:50:27.204|10309    |10309                  |
  # |2  |2022-04-18 21:26:25.671|2022-04-18 21:26:36.313|11       |11                     |
  # |3  |2022-04-18 21:27:12.388|2022-04-18 21:27:27.227|15       |15                     |
  # |4  |2022-04-19 09:57:40.453|2022-04-29 09:59:07.612|864087   |691287                 |
  # +---+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-----------------------+
  ```